# Python How to call a class method without importing

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, methods, python-requests

I found this piece of code in this repo. https://github.com/adw0rd/instagrapi/blob/master/instagrapi/mixins/fbsearch.py

And I wonder how `self.private_request()` could be called because there is no import and `private_request()` isn't defined in this class.

```
from instagrapi.extractors import extract_location


class FbSearchMixin:

    def fbsearch_places(self, query: str, lat: float = 40.74, lng: float = -73.94):
        params = {
            'search_surface': 'places_search_page',
            'timezone_offset': self.timezone_offset,
            'lat': lat,
            'lng': lng,
            'count': 30,
            'query': query,
        }
        result = self.private_request("fbsearch/places/", params=params)
        locations = []
        for item in result['items']:
            locations.append(extract_location(item['location']))
        return locations
```

It would be glad if someone could explain why and how this is possible.

Comment: `private_request` is another method in the SAME class.

Comment: Doesn't have to be defined in this module as long as it's defined in the context where someone uses it. This class says it's a mixin, so presumably whatever it is mixed in with should define that method.

Comment: @balderman same class ? What does that mean for you ? nothing more in the file, and no inheritance

Comment: @azro as far as I understand that code can **not** run "as is"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code doesn't call `fbsearch_places`; only defines it. If it called it without defining `private_request`, that would cause an exception.

But if someone imports this code and uses this class in combination with another class where `private_request` *is* defined, then they will be able to use the `fbsearch_places` method.

That's what "mix in" means in `FbSearchMixin`: that the class that is supposed to be used in combination with another class in multiple inheritance.

Comment: private_request() is defined in class PrivateRequestMixin in private.py